# Bicycle Computer Mount for Small Diameter Handlebars

Tags: steel, bike-computer

I have a steel bike with handlebars that are about half as thick as today's bikes. Where can I find a computer mount for these bars or should I just use some type of spacer? Thanks!

Comment: Pieces of old inner tube work well for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most computer mounts come with plastic spacers that can be placed between the hard plastic mount and the handlebar. If yours didn't come with that, I have used Athletic tape to build up the bars to the point where the mount will grip the bars adequately.

Comment: Or electrical tape.